# In Opam how do I tell which package owns a given file?

Tags: ocaml, opam

In Opam how do I tell which package owns a given file under `${OPAMROOT}/system`?  If there is no direct mean to achieve this, is it possible to list files owned by a given package?

Comment: the directories in the lib and build directories should be named by the package they came from. the config and install files are named by the package. I'm guessing, you might be wondering about something else though.

Comment: @nlucaroni Bingo! There are a few exceptions, like findlib installing (or not) META files for camlp4. I am looking for a systematic tool that always work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such facility, as `opam` allows packages to install their files virtually everywhere. But in general structure is quite simple and most packages respect it:

1. Each installed package has its own subfolder in `lib`, `etc`, `doc` and `share`.
2. For each package `opam` creates an entry `install/<package-name>.install` that may contain files that this package installed, if special facilities, provided by opam, were used in the installation process.
3. binaries are put into `bin` or `sbin` without further subdivision.

Comment: It looks like there is no positive answer to the question! Your suggestions match my own usage and this is probably as far as we can go in this direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The following command lists all packages and the files included in them - one can dump the output to a file to search it.

```
opam list -s | xargs -t -n 1 opam show --list-files > files.txt 2>&1
```

(tested with opam 2.1)